# ZMODEM CRC-32 FCS Issues

Tags: c#, crc32, crc16, zmodem

I found many questions and answers on this topic. But I still stuck with ZModem stuff.
I'm stuck with CRC-32 stuff at the end of the frame (FCS).
I wanted to know on which part of the ZFile header frame is calculated this checksum? Is the calculation include frame type, encoding type, ZCRCW bytes, ...? Or juste ZFs/ ZCRCS, and informations.
I also wanted to know if it's possible to calculated the CRC of the frame on the base of the entire frame values?
And Is it possible to find a CRC calculation example in CRC-16 and/or CRC32 with explanations?
I'm c# so I'm sometimes lost in Zmodem specs.
Thks in advance